# Water bottle rivnuts preventing dropper post getting low enough, carbon frame

Tags: repair, carbon, dropper

I didn't realise this bike had a second set of drink bottle bolt holes on vertical length of the front triangle, they're stopping the seat post getting as low as I would like it.

If I drill the rivnuts out there's going to be a hole in the frame directly over the bottom bracket, what're the options for sealing the hole up? Are there any special considerations for drilling the nut out of a carbon frame?

Additionally does anyone know an internally routed dropper with 27.2mm diameter that has 150mm of travel?

Bike: 2021 Polygon Syncline C2 - Medium Frame
https://www.polygonbikes.com/product/mountain/syncline-c2/

[image]

Comment: Special considerations  - 'don't' comes to mind.  You will weaken the frame, enough to cause failure, who knows. You will also void any warranty.  Consider a shorter dropper or selling the bike and buying one suitable for 150mm dropper.

Comment: If you unscrew the bolts from the rivnuts, does that help get the dropper post any lower?

Comment: Do you have access to one of those cameras on a stick?  AKA a bore scope camera?  They're super handy for seeing down inside things like frames.

Comment: @mattnz How is it going to weaken the frame? If it's done correctly no carbon should be touched.

The dropper pictured is 105mm

Comment: @Criggie Nah it's the riv nuts themselves blocking the post not the bolts, RE the camera I can clearly see the back of the rivnuts with the seat tube removed

Comment: It may be worth asking Polygon directly - they may have a dropper post idea that fits better without this change.

Comment: What is your target seat height?

Comment: @Criggie yep will send them an email, such a PITA, I had seen a video with the small frame and it doesn't have the bolts so didn't even think to check if the larger sizes did...

Comment: @Nathan Knutson it's pretty much perfect for pedalling efficiency at the top of this 105mm dropper as installed, but I'd rather have the option to sacrifice that for being able to drop the seat fully into the frame, it's a bit restrictive for manuals and hops

Comment: @Kieran I ask because with that information, plus knowing exactly what dropper you have (rom which saddletop to rail of the saddle can be inferred), plus knowing the distance from the seattube opening to the interference spot, one can go shopping for a seatpost that won't have the issue. Droppers are mostly pretty close in their overall length but there are outliers too. It's worth preserving your warranty if you can help it.

Comment: @Nathan Knutson fair point, will get out the tape measure tonight and check!

Comment: Consider that any unauthorised change will likely void any warranty on the frame.  I mean, "unauthorised by the manufacturer"

Comment: The bike wasn't probably designed for use with a dropper post in mind.

Comment: Saw the end off the post.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Is that safe to do with a dropper post?

Comment: @Carel 27.2mm = definitely not.

Comment: @Michael May lead to a small explosion and the post not working anymore, but otherwise it’ll be fine.

Comment: @Michael depends on the post

Comment: Note that rivnuts may serve a structural purpose. I imagine they reinforce the hole and apply a compressive force that mitigates cracks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a cycle shop, it is not uncommon for people with carbon or aluminium frames to come in with the problem that one of the bottle cage bolts has corroded and become stuck in the rivnut, or crossthreaded and stuck so they both turn together.

In this instance, the shop does what it can to remove the bolt (this is often time consuming) before drilling out the rivnut and fitting a new one.

What you are proposing to do is much less damaging to the frame than removing a stuck bottle cage bolt. It is unlikely that you will make a problem if you do this carefully. A shop would have insurance against a faulty repair but if you choose to do this yourself, you are on your own regarding safety.

Holes can be covered by vinyl stickers.

Have fun, but think carefully what you are doing before committing.

Comment: I wonder if there's a hollow rivet that could be inserted to protect the edges, something like an eyelet for a sail, aka a grommet or grommit. But not deep enough to interfere with OP's seatpost.

Comment: If it's a concern, epoxy resin could be used to ensure that no loose strands of carbon get tweaked out of position @Criggie . Often (usually) the post slides right up against the inside of the tube so an eyelet would still interfere.

Comment: good point - perhaps the dropper should be greased/lubed and then used as a backer while adding "something" to fill in the hole.  That should stop it sticking, while still proving enough room for the dropper.